# Enable controller service in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using SelectHiveQL processor within that I am using HiveConnectionPool controller service to connect to Hive.

I try to disable once but it got stuck and then my controller service is not having any symbol for enable/disable.

[image]

Could anyone know that how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, if it got stuck during a client->server operation, I think you have to wait up to 5 mins or something. The version of Hive (1.2.1) doesn't support a client-side timeout, so IIRC it has to wait to whatever the timeout is set to on the server side.